# Plone Dexterity RelationChoice widget clashes with jQueryUI?

Tags: jquery-ui, plone, jquery-ui-autocomplete, dexterity

A RelationChoice widget in my custom type works fine until `collective.js.jqueryui autocomplete` is enabled and then it stops working ie stops doing relation lookups; nothing happens when you type in the field.

(In another part of the site I use `collective.js.jqueryui autocomplete` with Google Maps API to return address suggestions as the user completes an address field.)

The current workaround is to disable `collective.js.jqueryui autocomplete` when i want to use the RelationChoice widget (and re-enable afterwards). Not a good solution.

- Plone 4.2.1.1
- collective.js.jqueryui 1.8.16.9 (also tried 1.10.0.1 - same clash)
- plone.app.dexterity 1.2.1

Independantly:

- If i only enable `plone.formwidget.autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.min.js` my Google maps lookup doesnt fire (see code below) but the RelationChoice widget works
- If i only enable `collective.js.jqueryui autocomplete` my Google maps lookup works but the RelationChoice widget doesnt fire

Code sample:

---

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initialize();

        $(function() { // Google maps lookup
            $("#address").autocomplete({
                //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
                source: function(request, response) {
                geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term}, function(results, status) { ...
```

---

```
    ... <input type="text" name="address" id="address" autocomplete="off" class="ac_input">
```

Is it possible I could re-use `plone.formwidget.autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.min.js` in the above code instead? I don't know how to get it to fire my Google maps lookup...? (`collective.js.jqueryui autocomplete` successfully activates the above function when enabled.)

Comment: Please include some exerpts of relevant code.

Comment: Could toutpt's answer solve your conflict?

Comment: Too bad toutp's and my answers couldn't help futher, seems you need to make a closer js-debug-session. Could you proceed any further? And could you paste the js-lines concerning the google-widget?

Comment: I have a workaround. I looked at changing out jqueryui library for "select2" library, but didnt want to rewrite my google maps address lokup function, so instead I have added a conditional to the jsregistry.xml so that collective.js.jqueryui.custom.min.js is not called if

expression="python:'my-page-with-relationChoice-widget' not in context.portal_url.getRelativeContentPath(context)"

So there is no clash on the autocomplete function in the relationChoice form widget 

Hope the extra overhead per page is ok, i know this is not great but it's a workaround for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have done It. At least on Plone 4.3

The first part was, to fully enable the jQuery ui effects in the package. There is a namespace problem and a missing file, that results in `.effects() is not a function`.

First, download the correct jQueryUI version cd into it and

```
jquery=/buildout_dir/parts/omelette/collective/js/jqueryui

cp jquery.ui.effect.min.js $jquery/js/jquery.ui.effect.core.min.js
```

then cd into the `$jquery` directory and convert all effect packages to correct namespace. Eg:

```
mv js/jquery.ui.effect-highlight.min.js js/jquery.ui.effect.highlight.min.js
```

Then replace all occurrences of `effects` with `effect` `$jquery/config.py`. In vim use

```
:1,$s/effects/effect/g
```

Secondly, to enable the jQuery based autocomplete widget, cd into the src directory of your buildout and

```
 git clone https://github.com/plone/plone.formwidget.autocomplete.git plone.formwidget.autocomplete
 git checkout jqueryui-autocomplete
```

then edit your `versions.cfg`. For me

```
plone.formwidget.autocomplete >= 2.0
```

works. Then edit your `buildout.cfg` and add the package under `zcml` and `develop`. I did a buildout, but it may be enough to restart Zope. The last step is obviously, to visit the portal installer and reinstall the product.

**Update**

As described in the comments, it was not fully functional. I further had to modify one .js file, namely `autocomplete.js` from the `plone.formwidget.autocomplete` package. Here is the result

http://pastebin.com/RPaLk80H

This all together makes the RelationChoiceWidget and the AutocompleteWidget work **together** in one form. I like it.

I also filed a bug report on github for the jQueryUI package.

Comment: Thanks ansi_lumen. So that's a monkey patch on collective.js.jqueryui? Thanks for tracking that down. I think I'll leave my conditional for now and when (if) the namespace clash is fixed then i'll remove it...

Comment: I must admit that I posted this after throwing my night at it. Now the widget gets displayed as expected, but it does not really work. I did a `console.log(d)` on the included `autocomplete.js`, which seems to get a wrong data format from the popup and throws an error. I think I need to solve it "finally" in the next days and will update my report in case...

Comment: @ansi_lumen: Great, muchas gracias! You can help even more people, if you'd report this also on github.com/plone/plone.formwidget.autocomplete/issues/5, would that be possible for you?

Comment: Pull request issued, jQueryui package got fixed after bug report. What would be the single reason to vote me down here??

Comment: @ansi_lumen: No idea who voted you down (maybe the person can leave a note here why?), +1 from me anyway, I haven't reviewed but the package-owners hopefully will soon and merge your contribution. Very much appreciated you took the effort to share, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Contenttree widget is based on autocomplete widget.

Autocomplete widget conflict with jqueryui autocomplete plugin.

Using collective.js.jqueryui you can unactivate the autocomplete plugin using the portal_registry.

It makes years that ploneformwidget.autocomplete is broken with jqueryui. There is a branch of plone.formwidget.autocomplete which is based on jqueryui (the branch 2.0) but I don't have already test it with contenttree widget.

So to fix your issue: go to jqueryui controlpanel and uncheck autocomplete plugin.

Comment: This is the same answer that I gave before, just that you advice to put off the Plone-core-jQuery-option instead of the js of p.f.autocomplete. I think, the latter should remove the contained js'ses and also use the given jQuery-packages instead -> avoid redundancy and skript-conflicts.

Comment: Conflict reported: https://github.com/plone/plone.formwidget.autocomplete/issues/5

Answer (score 1):

**Update** (according to the question's update):

Referring to Martin's tutorial and the [section about relations](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/references), Dexterity pulls plone.formwidget.contenttree, which pulls plone.formwidget.contenttree, which pulls plone.formwidget.autocomplete.

The latter includes jQuery's autocomplete-sources, so does collective.js.jqueryui, pulled by your map-product. A conflict is very likely.

Try this:

- Go to http://yourhost.org:8080/yourSiteId/portal_javascripts/manage_workspace
- Uncheck '++resource++plone.formwidget.autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.min.js' and hit save at the bottom. Make sure debug-mode is on (checkbox is in the very top for that).

Comment: OK i disabled autocomplete in zmi, but then the widget doesnt work.

Comment: I re-enabled the autocomplete js in zmi and switched off the jquery-ui autocomplete but then my google map breaks.

Comment: I notice there is a 'restrict to authenticated users' flag for the js autocomplete in zmi js_registry. In theory if i turn this off, then i can activate this autocomplete for my google app as well, trouble is i dont know what activation the widget uses... jquery-ui uses `.autocomplete` but i cant figure out how to activate the relationWidget autocomplete... i tried making the class of the input `autocompleteInputWidget` but it doesnt fire the autocomplete event on input...